# Sequelize - how to make a correct association so the userid becomes the authored for reviews?

Tags: postgresql, nodes, sequelize.js

For an online shop, I am trying to make an association so the user id becomes the authored and thought its enough if I do that:Review.belongsTo(User, {as:'author'}) - however, its not and all authorId's are null. Any help would be appreciated!

My association:

```
Review.belongsTo(User, {as:'author'})
```

My model:

```
   var Review = db.define('review', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
   content: {
       type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    rating: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        validate:{
            min: 0,
            max:5
        }
});

module.exports = Review;
```

My route for reviews:

```
router.post('/:productId', function(req,res,next){
  Review.create(req.body) // OB/SB: watch out for abuse
  .then(function(review){
      return review.reload({include: [{model: User, as: 'author'}]})
    })
  .then(function(reviewId){
        res.status(201).json(reviewId);
  })
     .catch(next)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For association:

```
Review.belongsTo(User, {as:'author'})
```

Your model should be like

```
   var Review = db.define('review', {
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    authorId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: true
        }
   content: {
       type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    rating: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        validate:{
            min: 0,
            max:5
        }
});

module.exports = Review;
```